# Have any players ever won an NCAA basketball championship with two different teams?

Tags: trivia, basketball, collegiate

Are there any players who have won an NCAA basketball championship while playing for two different teams?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, and can't easily find evidence.  I can't even find a list of players to win two championships for the same team.  There's not a lot of statistics easily available for NCAA basketball, unfortunately.  Even Sports-reference.com doesn't seem to have an easy way to find this.

Answer (score 10):

No player has ever won NCAA basketball championships with multiple teams.

The player who came closest to achieving this is Bob Bender.  He was on the undefeated [1976 Indiana team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1975%E2%80%9376_Indiana_Hoosiers_men%27s_basketball_team#Roster) that won the national championship, and he was also on the [1978 Duke team](http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/duke/1978.html) that lost to Kentucky in the title game.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Bender) says Bob Bender is the only college basketball player to reach the NCAA championship game for two different teams:

> Bender has the distinction of being the only individual to play on two different teams in two different NCAA Championship games.