# Have any players ever won an NCAA football championship with two different teams?

Tags: american-football, trivia, collegiate

Are there any players who have won an NCAA football championship while playing for two different teams?

Comment: As your answer implies, this is difficult to answer since NCAA football championships are not well-defined (unless you are referring to the actual [NCAA Football Championship](http://www.ncaa.com/championships/football/fcs)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this answer while researching the [basketball version](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/9018/have-any-players-ever-won-an-ncaa-basketball-championship-with-two-different-tea) of this question.

J.T. White won a football championship at Ohio State in 1942 and then at Michigan in 1947.

[This page](http://www.secsportsfan.com/what-player-won-national-championships-with-two-different-teams.html) says the following:

> Q: What college football player won national championships with two different teams?
>
> A: According to Kent Stephens, curator at the College Football Hall of Fame:
>
> "If you regard Michigan as claiming a piece of the 1947 title then JT White played there and at Ohio State in 1942."

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College_football_national_championships_in_NCAA_Division_I_FBS) confirms that Ohio State shared the football national championship in 1942 and Michigan shared the football national championship in 1947.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._T._White) also confirms that JT White played football for Ohio State in 1942 and Michigan in 1947.

Answer (score 3):

On 11th January 2016, [Jake Coker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jake_Coker) won a [National Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_College_Football_Playoff_National_Championship) at the University of Alabama. He was the backup quarterback for Florida State when they won the BCS National Championship in 2013, so he now has two championships from two different schools.

Answer (score 0):

In 1917 Julian “Judy” Harlan played for the Golden Tornados of Georgia Tech.  In 1918 after joining the Navy football  team , they too won a National championship

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please post answers with valid sources.